# Firebase-node.js localhost server throwing SSL_PROTOCOL error when i try to fetch data from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to create my backend server using node and firebase, but when i try to fetch data from it i get an error: "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". 
My firebase/functions/index.js file is

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const express = require("express");

    const app = express();
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("hello firebase");
    });

    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And index.html running on VSCode liveServer on port 5500 is just the emmet skeleton with `<script>fetch('https://localhost:5000').then(res=>res.text()).then(res=>console.log(res));</script>` in body tag. Finally, the firebase.json is

```
    {
      "functions": {
        "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
      },
      "hosting": {
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "/",
            "function": "app"
          }
        ],
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
      }
    }
```

I guess it's good to mention that when i go to localhost:5000 in browser i get the expected 'hello firebase'

@edit: I've set up pure express server and bahaiviour doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turned out i just had to add `cors` to the server and everything works just fine. The working code is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello firebase");
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```